# How to drag and drop a column into another

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using: jquery.dataTables.js from: https://datatables.net

I am trying to drag and drop a column from one table to another.

**EDIT:**
so basically what I want to do is:

- be able to drag and drop the names from table 2 into column called **name** in the table above
- after drag and drop the name the same should disappear from the table 2.

**case 2: if I add a new row** using the button **Add new Row**

- I need be able to drag a drop the names from table 2 into that column **name** too.

so basically I want to do a drag and drop just in the column not in the row.

I don't want create a new row just move the names from 1 table to another.

**EDIT 2:**

**1- Can you drag/drop multiples values from Table #2 to Table #1?** 
no, the drag and drop will be possible just 1 by 1.
The drag and drop will be just possible after the user clicks in edit or add a new  row.
so I will be able to replace names drom table 2 into the column names table 1

**2- If no, the value dragged shall then replace the value where it is dropped?** 
yes

**3- If yes,how should it work? Adding new rows with the other values blank? 
no row need be added, we just need replace the column name.**

**how will works:**
so after click in edit or add new row i will be able to drag a name from table 2 into column in
table 1.

**few more resquests if possible:**
if select the row in table 2, this row should be change the color, showing was selected. and in the table 1 collun name where this need be dropped need to change the color to show the
user can be dropped.

sample working here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/6sbmBzbXDzm4p6CjaVK0?p=preview

```js
   $(document).ready(function() {
 var dataUrl = 'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/ccTtqmPbkO?indent=2';
var options = [
  { key : 'option 1', value : 1 },
  { key : 'option 2', value : 2 },
  { key : 'option 3', value : 3 }
];

$(document).ready(function() {
  var $table = $('#example');
  var dataTable = null;

  $table.on('mousedown', 'td .fa.fa-minus-square', function(e) {
    dataTable.row($(this).closest("tr")).remove().draw();
  });

  $table.on('mousedown.edit', 'i.fa.fa-pencil-square', function(e) {
    enableRowEdit($(this));
  });

  $table.on('mousedown', 'input', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

  $table.on('mousedown.save', 'i.fa.fa-envelope-o', function(e) {
    updateRow($(this), true); // Pass save button to function.
  });

  $table.on('mousedown', '.select-basic', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

  dataTable = $table.DataTable({
    ajax: dataUrl,
    rowReorder: {
      dataSrc: 'order',
      selector: 'tr'
    },
    columns: [{
      data: 'order'
    }, {
      data: 'name'
    }, {
      data: 'place'
    }, {
      data: 'delete'
    }]
  });

  $table.css('border-bottom', 'none')
        .after($('<div>').addClass('addRow')
          .append($('<button>').attr('id', 'addRow').text('Add New Row')));

  // Add row
  $('#addRow').click(function() {
    var $row = $("#new-row-template").find('tr').clone();
    dataTable.row.add($row).draw();
    // Toggle edit mode upon creation.
    enableRowEdit($table.find('tbody tr:last-child td i.fa.fa-pencil-square'));
  });

  $('#btn-save').on('click', function() {
    updateRows(true); // Update all edited rows
  });

  $('#btn-cancel').on('click', function() {
    updateRows(false); // Revert all edited rows
  });

  function enableRowEdit($editButton) {
    $editButton.removeClass().addClass("fa fa-envelope-o");
    var $row = $editButton.closest("tr").off("mousedown");

    $row.find("td").not(':first').not(':last').each(function(i, el) {
      enableEditText($(this))
    });

    $row.find('td:first').each(function(i, el) {
      enableEditSelect($(this))
    });
  }
  
  function enableEditText($cell) {
    var txt = $cell.text();
    $cell.empty().append($('<input>', {
      type : 'text',
      value : txt
    }).data('original-text', txt));
  }

  function enableEditSelect($cell) {
    var txt = $cell.text();
    $cell.empty().append($('<select>', {
      class : 'select-basic'
    }).append(options.map(function(option) {
      return $('<option>', {
        text  : option.key,
        value : option.value
      })
    })).data('original-value', txt));
}

  function updateRows(commit) {
     $table.find('tbody tr td i.fa.fa-envelope-o').each(function(index, button) {
      updateRow($(button), commit);
    });
  }

  function updateRow($saveButton, commit) {
    $saveButton.removeClass().addClass('fa fa-pencil-square');
    var $row = $saveButton.closest("tr");

    $row.find('td').not(':first').not(':last').each(function(i, el) {
      var $input = $(this).find('input');
      $(this).text(commit ? $input.val() : $input.data('original-text'));
    });

    $row.find('td:first').each(function(i, el) {
      var $input = $(this).find('select');
      $(this).text(commit ? $input.val() : $input.data('original-value'));
    });
  }
});

 $(document).ready(function() {
      var url = 'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bXcKDeAbyq?indent=2';
      table = $('#example2').DataTable({
        ajax: url,
        order: [[ 0, "desc" ]],
        rowReorder: {
          dataSrc: 'place',
          selector: 'tr'
        },
        columns: [ {
          data: 'name'
        }]
      });

    }); 
});
```

```css
 div.addRow {
      line-height: 45px;
      background-color: #fff;
      padding-left: 10px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid;
      border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    }
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/DataTables/RowReorder/ce6d240e/js/dataTables.rowReorder.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/rowreorder/1.2.0/css/rowReorder.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

 <table id="example" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>order</th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>country</th>
      <th>action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>

<table id="new-row-template" style="display:none">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>999</td> <!-- Use a large number or row might be inserted in the middle -->
      <td>__NAME__</td>
      <td>__COUNTRY__</td>
      <td>
        <i class="fa fa-pencil-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-minus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<div class="pull-right">
  <button type="button" id="btn-cancel" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
  <button type="button" id="btn-save" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
</div>

<br>
<br>
<h1>
 table 2
</h1><br>
<br>
<table id="example2" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>


<br>
<br>
<h1>
 table 2
</h1><br>
<br>
<table id="example2" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Try https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/30197/add-remove-table-rows-on-drag-and-drop-between-two-datatables

Comment: that cases it is rows to rows, i am looking column to column, thank you

Comment: To be 100% clear: 1- Can you drag/drop multiples values from Table #2 to Table #1? 2- If no, the value dragged shall then replace the value where it is dropped? 3- If yes,how should it work? Adding new rows with the other values blank?

Comment: No, i don't think you cannot drag multiple columns at a time. Although you can think of dragging the header and dropping it on another table. That can't work very well as table1 and table2 may not have same number of columns. If you drag one only column, then it is considered as a single row which you can get idea from the link I gave you.

Comment: Master DJon, I did edit my question with your answers, thank you.

Comment: You will either use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API or do something in JS, and/or write the missing functionality into the API, but people have already tackled the same problem you've described. Instead of rows, you'll do columns and I'm sure it can all be modified to do exactly what you want.

Comment: I am very novice it hard to me do this :(, thanks for all sugestions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery Datatable drag and drop a column from one table to another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42517640/jquery-datatable-drag-and-drop-a-column-from-one-table-to-another)

Answer (score 2):

I've made some changes to your code. Try it out please to see whether this resolution is appropriate for you:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dataUrl = 'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/ccTtqmPbkO?indent=2';
  var options = [{
      key: 'option 1',
      value: 1
    },
    {
      key: 'option 2',
      value: 2
    },
    {
      key: 'option 3',
      value: 3
    }
  ];

  var rowCache = [];

  function mouseUp(event) {
    var ctrl = $(document.elementsFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY)).filter('input.border-highlight');

    if (ctrl.length > 0 && rowCache.length > 0) {
      var el = rowCache[0];
      var data = el.row.data();

      if (data.length > 0) {
        ctrl.val(data[0].name);
        el.row.remove().draw();
      }
    }

    rowCache = [];
    $('#example tr td:nth-child(2) input').removeClass('border-highlight');
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    var $table = $('#example');
    var dataTable = null;

    $('body').mouseup(mouseUp);

    $table.on('mousedown', 'td .fa.fa-minus-square', function(e) {
      dataTable.row($(this).closest("tr")).remove().draw();
    });

    $table.on('mousedown.edit', 'i.fa.fa-pencil-square', function(e) {
      enableRowEdit($(this));
    });

    $table.on('mousedown', 'input', function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $table.on('mousedown.save', 'i.fa.fa-envelope-o', function(e) {
      updateRow($(this), true); // Pass save button to function.
    });

    $table.on('mousedown', '.select-basic', function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
    });

    dataTable = $table.DataTable({
      ajax: dataUrl,
      rowReorder: {
        dataSrc: 'order',
        selector: 'tr'
      },
      columns: [{
        data: 'order'
      }, {
        data: 'name'
      }, {
        data: 'place'
      }, {
        data: 'delete'
      }]
    });

    $table.css('border-bottom', 'none')
      .after($('<div>').addClass('addRow')
        .append($('<button>').attr('id', 'addRow').text('Add New Row')));

    // Add row
    $('#addRow').click(function() {
      var $row = $("#new-row-template").find('tr').clone();
      dataTable.row.add($row).draw();
      // Toggle edit mode upon creation.
      enableRowEdit($table.find('tbody tr:last-child td i.fa.fa-pencil-square'));
    });

    $('#btn-save').on('click', function() {
      updateRows(true); // Update all edited rows
    });

    $('#btn-cancel').on('click', function() {
      updateRows(false); // Revert all edited rows
    });

    function enableRowEdit($editButton) {
      $editButton.removeClass().addClass("fa fa-envelope-o");
      var $row = $editButton.closest("tr").off("mousedown");

      $row.find("td").not(':first').not(':last').each(function(i, el) {
        enableEditText($(this))
      });

      $row.find('td:first').each(function(i, el) {
        enableEditSelect($(this))
      });
    }

    function enableEditText($cell) {
      var txt = $cell.text();
      $cell.empty().append($('<input>', {
        type: 'text',
        value: txt
      }).data('original-text', txt));
    }

    function enableEditSelect($cell) {
      var txt = $cell.text();
      $cell.empty().append($('<select>', {
        class: 'select-basic'
      }).append(options.map(function(option) {
        return $('<option>', {
          text: option.key,
          value: option.value
        })
      })).data('original-value', txt));
    }

    function updateRows(commit) {
      $table.find('tbody tr td i.fa.fa-envelope-o').each(function(index, button) {
        updateRow($(button), commit);
      });
    }

    function updateRow($saveButton, commit) {
      $saveButton.removeClass().addClass('fa fa-pencil-square');
      var $row = $saveButton.closest("tr");

      $row.find('td').not(':first').not(':last').each(function(i, el) {
        var $input = $(this).find('input');
        $(this).text(commit ? $input.val() : $input.data('original-text'));
      });

      $row.find('td:first').each(function(i, el) {
        var $input = $(this).find('select');
        $(this).text(commit ? $input.val() : $input.data('original-value'));
      });
    }
  });

  $(document).ready(function() {
    var url = 'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bXcKDeAbyq?indent=2';
    table = $('#example2').DataTable({
      ajax: url,
      order: [
        [0, "desc"]
      ],
      rowReorder: {
        dataSrc: 'place',
        selector: 'tr'
      },
      columns: [{
        data: 'name'
      }]
    });

    table.on('mousedown', 'tbody tr', function() {
      var $row = $(this);

      var r = table.rows(function(i, data) {
        return data.name == $row.children().first().text();
      });

      if (r[0].length > 0) {
        $row.parents('table').find('tr').removeClass('highlight');
        $row.addClass('highlight');
        $('#example tr td:nth-child(2) input').addClass('border-highlight');
      }

      rowCache.push({
        row: r
      });
    });

  });

});
```

```css
div.addRow {
  line-height: 45px;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

tr.highlight td {
  background-color: #D0ECE7 !important;
}

.border-highlight {
  border-color: #D0ECE7 !important;
  border-width: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowreorder/1.2.0/js/dataTables.rowReorder.min.js"></script>

<link data-require="datatables@*" data-semver="1.10.12" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowreorder/1.2.0/css/rowReorder.dataTables.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<table id="example" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>order</th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>country</th>
      <th>action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>

<table id="new-row-template" style="display:none">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>999</td>
      <!-- Use a large number or row might be inserted in the middle -->
      <td>__NAME__</td>
      <td>__COUNTRY__</td>
      <td>
        <i class="fa fa-pencil-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-minus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<div class="pull-right">
  <button type="button" id="btn-cancel" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
  <button type="button" id="btn-save" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
</div>

<br>
<br>
<h1>
  table 2
</h1><br>
<br>
<table id="example2" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f7debwj2/47/

Answer (score 1):

First thing first, bind click event for table 2 td to grab the data which is really simple. Then I would write mouseup function as follows on table 1:

```
$('table-id-class').on('mouseup', 'td', function (e) {
    console.log(e.html());
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

The above event would give you exact position of the td, you are left with changing value for the TD. I am sure datatables must be having some way to change values in order to go that value in data. Good luck!